# Can I refresh the scope if i'm already in an $apply phase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function let's say:

```
$scope.addNode = function (param) {
    //this is a function to add a child to a tree view node, sent via the param argument
    var newNode = { 
        //add the different properties I need for the new node
    };
    if(param.hasOwnProperty('children') && param.children != null) {
        param.children.push(newNode);
    }
    else {
        param.children = [];
        param.children.push(newNode);
    }

    $scope.$apply(); // calling $apply because I need the newNode to be rendered

    $scope.setFocusedNode(newNode); //highlight the new node, change attributes, etc
    $scope.editNodeText(newNode); //call inline Editing for the new node, which also involves DOM manipulation; this is basically where everything fails because without the apply, the DOM element for the newNode doesn't exist.

}
```

I use this same function from a jquery keyup event and from a ng-click directive. 
The code works okay from the keyup event but when calling it from the directive I get an "$apply already in progress" error because ng-click already does the $apply innately.

However, removing the $apply also doesn't work because I need the scope to be updated for the code following it AND I can't replace ng-click with a normal onclick because the click function is also a property of an object in the scope and can change.

Is there a way to say "refresh scope here" without getting the "$apply already in progress" error? Note that Even tho I get the error, the scope gets updated corectly and works okay even when being called from ng-click (except in IE which just chokes and the javascript stops working altogether)

Comment: You can consider this https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma

Comment: @Joel_Blum I have tried that but It's not what I'm looking for. I still need to do the $apply even when I'm calling the function from the ng-click (and thus, inside an implicit apply) because I need the scope to be updated for the next part of the function.

Comment: Can you give some more code ? what is it that you do before and after the apply ?  I think you need to find a cleaner solution ...

Comment: I agree with @Joel_Blum, mixing jQuery and angular this way is very bad practice

Comment: I will update the OP with some more details.

Comment: Done, it's basically the gist of what it does and I can't think of a way out of it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. The code now looks like this:

```
$scope.addNode = function (param) {
    //this is a function to add a child to a tree view node, sent via the param argument
    var newNode = { 
        //add the different properties I need for the new node
    };
    if(param.hasOwnProperty('children') && param.children != null) {
        param.children.push(newNode);
    }
    else {
        param.children = [];
        param.children.push(newNode);
    }


    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.setFocusedNode(newNode); //highlight the new node, change attributes, etc
        $scope.editNodeText(newNode); //call inline Editing for the new node, which also involves DOM manipulation; this is basically where everything fails because without the apply, the DOM element for the newNode doesn't exist.
    }, 0);

}
```

And I simply called $scope.$apply(addNode) when calling it from the jquery keyup function.

What the $timeout does is delay the two functions until the browser has finished rendering the changes to the $scope. I don't fully understand how it does it but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

the right way is to remove `$scope.$apply` from the function and
when calling from jquery use

```
$scope.apply($scope.addNode(arguments));
```

and when calling the function from within angular use

```
$scope.addNode(arguments);
```

Comment: I tried that, but I can't do it like that due to the second commented section. the function is basically `add node, render node (this is where I need the apply), do something with the rendered node`. If I envelop everything in an Apply the node still isn't rendered when I reach phase 3.

Comment: then it's wrong practice to use the same function... you either use two different functions or you can do it dirty way - check the $scope.$$phase inside the function before $apply -> if (!$scope.$$phase) {$scope.$apply();}

Comment: but it doesn't make sense that you need to call apply even if the digest cycle is already in progress

Comment: Changed the OP to add more detail. It seems like the only way is to change the way the function works altogether and it still won't work from inside the ng-click directive simply because I have to tell the scope to refresh before I move on to the next step and that will throw an error...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$scope.addNode = function (node) {
     $scope.$apply(function () {
            //do something to $scope object
        });

    //do something that needs the scope to be refreshed
}
```

Comment: it's the same... if you call it from within angular, the digest will be already in progress

Comment: it won't... the problem is that the function is reused in both cases - called from jquery, called from angular. It has to be called differently for each of these cases to avoid digest errors

Comment: @doodeec I can't even call it differently. I still need the $scope.$apply at that spot whether or not it's in ng-click or in the keyup event. I'll change the opening post to clarify.